# Knockout JS subscribe to 2 observables in a such a way that if either of the 2 change, I only get notified once

Tags: javascript, typescript, mvvm, knockout.js, observer-pattern

I have a timestamp filter where a user can change start and end time.
Which user changes either of the 2, subscribe callback works just fine.
However, When the user changes both start and end time in one edit mode, my subscribing function gets called twice, as expected.
I want to avoid this and I want it to be called only once. Any suggestions on how I can achieve that?

Comment: Add some code here to check

Answer (score 0):

In KO 3.4.0+, you can use [deferred updates](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/deferred-updates.html) on a computed that relies on both `start` and `end` in a way that causes a change even if `start` and `end` are changed in complementary ways:

```
let eitherX = 1;
const either = ko.computed(() => {
    start();
    end();
    return ++eitherX;
});
either.extend({deferred: true});
```

Live Example:

```js
const start = ko.observable(10);
const end = ko.observable(20);
let eitherX = 1;
const either = ko.computed(() => {
    start();
    end();
    return ++eitherX;
});
either.extend({deferred: true});

console.log("Subscribing");
// Setting deferred
either.subscribe(() => console.log("notified"));
console.log("changing start");
start(11);
console.log("changing end");
end(19);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

In earlier versions, you can use a [rate limit](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html) of `0`:

```
let eitherX = 1;
const either = ko.computed(() => {
    start();
    end();
    return ++eitherX;
});
either.extend({rateLimit: 0});
```

Live Example:

```js
const start = ko.observable(10);
const end = ko.observable(20);
let eitherX = 1;
const either = ko.computed(() => {
    start();
    end();
    return ++eitherX;
});
either.extend({rateLimit: 0});

console.log("Subscribing");
// Applying the rate limit
either.subscribe(() => console.log("notified"));
console.log("changing start");
start(11);
console.log("changing end");
end(19);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

---

You need `eitherX` so that teh value of `either` is always different when it's recomputed. If you tried to define `either` in terms of `start` and `end` (for instance, `start() + end()`), if you changed `start` and `end` in complementary ways (adding one to `start` and subtracting one from `end`), `either`'s value wouldn't change and you'd get no notification.

Answer (score 0):

Crowder above here is right when you are programmatically changing both filters at the same time and you only wish to trigger a callback once, when you are waiting for a user to change the filters one after the other, that's another thing.

There's really no way of knowing whether a user is going to change the endtime or not, after changing the starttime, so how would you know how long to wait for the starttime trigger to eventually fire?

The only alternative is to add a button after the 2 input filters that says "Confirm filter" and trigger the callback on that.

Actually, there's another way but in involves effectively doing two callback with the first being cancelled mid-go when the 2nd triggers and that's probably something you wish to avoid, right?